# Creating New Shared NativeScript Project doesn't work

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

When I run the following:

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics myProject --shared
```

It does not work. I have installed the schematic and everything according to the docs but that command does nothing. Any ideas?

I have followed the documentation here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

I checked for an invalid .angular.json but there is not one in my home directory.

I am running angular 6.0.3

There are no errors, I run the command it waits about 5 seconds and just returns doing nothing.

I found that I was running the wrong version of the Angular CLI, but I have upgraded and now when I run the build for iOS I get the following:

```
Error: Cannot connect to device socket.The error message is Device socket port cannot be found. 
at Errors.fail (/Users/jonathan/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:125:28)
at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/Users/jonathan/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:135:21)
at AppDebugSocketProxyFactory.<anonymous> (/Users/jonathan/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/device-sockets/ios/app-debug-socket-proxy-factory.js:105:38)
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at rejected (/Users/jonathan/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/device-sockets/ios/app-debug-socket-proxy-factory.js:5:65)
```

The Emulator opens and the app gets installed on the emulator but crashes as soon as it starts. I have tried to make this work with just a hello world app and it works correctly. But when using the **shared** flag it does not work.

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly not working? Is it throwing errors while creating? If Yes, what you see in the error log? Also what is the Angular version you have installed globally?

Comment: I have updated the comment with more details